# Invert & cut images in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I invert and crop an image in Matlab without using `imcomplement()` and `imcrop()` built-in functions ?

Is there any algorithms to invert and cut an image?

Comment: This question is off-topic.... for so many reasons.  Please see the following webpage on how to ask a proper question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `imcomplement()` function give to you the negative image.
Secondly,  one way to crop and invert an image is using slicing.

Let's take an image:

`img = ones(100,100);`

To invert an image in 180 degrees you can use:

`im_flipped = img(end:-1:1, :);`

To invert an image (get the negative image) you can use:

`ìm_neg = 255 - img;`

To crop an image you can use:

`im_cropped = img(20:50, 20:50);`

Comment: Your "inversion" code mirror reflects the image; it doesn't find the compliment. You probably mean to do `255 - img` assuming the image type is `uint8`.

Comment: I should change "invert an image" for "invert an image in 180 degrees"?

Comment: Yes that would make sense. You can also add in what I said about the compliment and I'll vote on your answer.

Comment: done! If you execute this: `im_neg2 = imcomplement(im)` and after this: `response = (im_neg == im_neg2)`, we get a logical matrix with the same size of our image and all values of this matrix are 1 that means True!, Very nice observation!

Comment: i get it thanku so much :)

Answer (score 0):

At the MATLAB command prompt, type:

```
edit imcomplement.m
edit imcrop.m
```

This will allow you to see how these functions are implemented, and implement your own.